# PHP - Simple XML - Adding Nodes To Specific Location

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I want to be able to insert a couple of nodes within a particular child within my XML. This takes place on my PHP script. I basically get given a 'unique_app_key'. So I want to check that against all Children within my XML doc, and then add some additional nodes within that.

This is my XML file:

```
<user unique_user_id="USER_ID">

    <app unique_app_key="APP_ID_1">
        <event index="0">
            <event_name>Name0</event_name>
            <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
        </event>
        <event index="1">
            <event_name>Name1</event_name>
            <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
        </event>
    </app>


    <app unique_app_key="APP_ID_2">
        <event index="0">
            <event_name>Name0</event_name>
            <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
        </event>
        <event index="1">
            <event_name>Name1</event_name>
            <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
        </event>
    </app>


    <app unique_app_key="APP_ID_3">
        <event index="0">
            <event_name>Name0</event_name>
            <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
        </event>
        <event index="1">
            <event_name>Name1</event_name>
            <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
        </event>
    </app>

</user>
```

So, lets say my PHP script has been given the 'unique_app_key' of 'APP_ID_2', how would I then add:

```
<event index="2">
    <event_name>Name2</event_name>
    <event_timestamp>0000000000</event_timestamp>
</event>
```

Within my current xml within the '`app unique_app_key="APP_ID_2`"' locations?

Comment: use `xpath()` to select the `<app>`with the right key, then `addChild()`.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad, I decipher the main problem you've got to add a child and closed against the duplicate. If that was wrong, please edit the question and make clear at which point you're running into which concrete problem.